Convert a Sphere into a hex-grid
I am looking in Three.js a sphere composed of circles, adjusted like a hex-grid.

The thing i need, is to generate the positions of all circles' centers, the rendering is not the problem.
I cannot find any algorithm that can provide those positions (in x,y,z coordinates).
Can you please help me ?

Maybe this forum topic will be useful/helpful: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/global-impacts-waves-trails/23445

Thx prisoner849. Note : it is beautiful :) The result of the points distribution is not what i am looking for. That give me some indication to where to look at. But i cannot find anything better than the Fibonacci Sphere distribution, which is amazing at the equator, but ugly at the poles. I know that there is better way to distribute the points, but i lost myself when i go into the code of the examples that i find great.
